# Selenium handling same link text for different elements with mouseover

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

System under test has three levels of mouseover: Level I–Level II –LevelIII. Once we mouseover to Level I, Level II is visible. Similarly mouseover to Level II to view Level III 
Problem: In some cases Level II link text is same as Level III. In those cases my code is selecting Level II link text instead of Level III as both of the link texts are visible and selenium picks up first one it find in DOM.
Assume: Level I link text is: A 
Level II link Texts Option: B | C | D |
Level III Options: X | Y | B

I’m wondering how to handle linktext B in this case as its always will select B from Level II instead of Level III.

Below is my code:

```
public boolean mouseOver(String levelI, String levelII, String levelIII) throws InterruptedException {
     try {
    waits.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("abc"));
     } catch (NoSuchElementException e) { 
     }
    boolean result = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while (attempts < 3) {

    try {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement selectAnEquipment = driver.findElement(By.linkText(levelI));
    action.moveToElement(selectAnEquipment).perform();
    WebElement mouselevelII = driver.findElement(By.linkText(levelII));
    action.moveToElement(mouselevelII).perform();           
    WebElement mouselevelIII = driver.findElement(By.linkText(levelIII));
    action.moveToElement(mouselevelIII).click().build().perform();
    result =true;
    break;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {    
    }
        attempts++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not very dynamically, you can find an element by xpath:

```
//find first element with link text = levelII
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'" + levelII + "')])[1]"));
//find second element with link text = levelIII
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'" + levelIII + "')])[2]"));
```

But if you don't know when levelII is equal levelIII, then I would do somethings like this:

```
List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElements(By.linkText(levelI));
List<WebElement> list2 = driver.findElements(By.linkText(levelII));
List<WebElement> list3 = driver.findElements(By.linkText(levelIII));

//now you can handle on it like
//if levelII == levelIII
if (list2.size() == 2 && list3.size() == 2) {
    //mouse over first founded element with link text = levelII = levelIII
    action.moveToElement(list2.get(0)).perform();
    //mouse over second founded element with link text = levelII = levelIII
    action.moveToElement(list3.get(1)).click().build().perform();
}
else {
    //the default handling in your code above
}
```

I hope it helps...